# Can we compare two Spotfire Dashboards and get the dfference in human language as the dxp file when unzipped creates XML files?

Tags: xml, spotfire

I am not asking for code rather asking like how should i approach as I am trying to do design thinking first to create a Spotfire code comparison tool. So, working on the design and feasibility part.

Comment: you would need to rely heavily on XPath and XSLT. there is a TON of great XSLT knowledge here on SO. godspeed to you; there is a reason this doesn't exist yet. but if you put together a good application you should pitch it to TIBCO! many customers have asked for this kind of comparison feature.

Comment: So, it seems there is no such tools made as of now for tibco spotfire. Thanks.

Comment: There's a 3rd-party addin for Spotfire (EPAM BI Version Control) that supposedly allows putting Spotfire dxp files under version control (including merging, diff etc.). I've never used it myself, but it might be useful - see https://www.epam.com/our-work/accelerators/epam-bi-version-control-for-tibco-spotfire.